# How to control the output of groupby in pandas to show the whole row not a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

this is a sample my dataframe(seasonal_name):

```
    season  winner  count   team_api_id team_long_name
1   2008/2009   10260   28  10260.0 Manchester United
2   2008/2009   8634    27  8634.0  FC Barcelona
3   2008/2009   8548    26  8548.0  Rangers
4   2008/2009   8650    25  8650.0  Liverpool
5   2008/2009   8636    25  8636.0  Inter
```

- I want to show highest count rows in each season with team_long_name, and for that i try this code:

> ```
> seasonal_name.groupby("season")["count"].max()
> ```

and its output is like this:

```
season
2008/2009    28
2009/2010    31
2010/2011    30
2011/2012    32
2012/2013    32
```

I want the output to contain the corresponding team_long_name and the other columns as well not just the count column.

Comment: Please show dataframe input and output as code. Not images.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with dropping duplicates (e.g. if 2 different teams have the same highest score for a season, only display 1 of the teams), you can do the following:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.groupby(["Season"])["Count"].idxmax()]
```

This first groups by `Season` and gets the indices of the rows having the maximum count for each season. We then locate those rows in `df` using `loc`.

The only issue is that `idxmax` only returns 1 row even if the maximum `Count` value for a season exists in multiple rows. Still, I hope this is a good starting point for you.

This is the code in action. The following is the example dataframe I used:

```
  Group  Count  Season
0     G      2  spring
1     G      3  summer
2     H      1  spring
3     H      4  summer
```

And this is what my line of code gives for `new_df`:

```
  Group  Count  Season
0     G      2  spring
3     H      4  summer
```

If you'd like to change the index of `new_df`, you can just do:

```
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Hope that helps.